# Check if all values in dataframe column are the same

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I want to do a quick and easy check if all column values for `counts` are the same in a dataframe:

In:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'names': ['Jim', 'Ted', 'Mal', 'Ted'], 'counts': [3, 4, 3, 3]}
pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

Out:

```
  names  counts
0   Jim       3
1   Ted       4
2   Mal       3
3   Ted       3
```

I want just a simple condition that `if all counts = same value` then `print('True')`.

Is there a fast way to do this?

Comment: what about `if len(df['counts'].unique()) ==1: print(True)`

Comment: `df.counts.nunique() == 1`?

Comment: Related: [Check if all elements in a list are identical](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3844801/2529619)

Comment: df.counts.drop_duplicates().shape[0] ==1

Answer (score 87, accepted):

An efficient way to do this is by comparing the first value with the rest, and using [`all`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.all.html):

```
def is_unique(s):
    a = s.to_numpy() # s.values (pandas<0.24)
    return (a[0] == a).all()

is_unique(df['counts'])
# False
```

Although the most intuitive idea could possibly be to count the amount of `unique` values and check if there is only one, this would have a needlessly high complexity for what we're trying to do. Numpy's' `np.unique`, called by pandas' `nunique`, implements a sorting of the underlying arrays, which has an evarage complexity of `O(n·log(n))` using [quicksort](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) (default). The above approach is `O(n)`.

The difference in performance becomes more obvious when we're applying this to an entire dataframe (see below).

---

### For an entire dataframe

In the case of wanting to perform the same task on an entire dataframe,  we can extend the above by setting `axis=0` in `all`:

```
def unique_cols(df):
    a = df.to_numpy() # df.values (pandas<0.24)
    return (a[0] == a).all(0)
```

For the shared example, we'd get:

```
unique_cols(df)
# array([False, False])
```

---

Here's a benchmark of the above methods compared with some other approaches, such as using `nunique` (for a **`pd.Series`**):

```
s_num = pd.Series(np.random.randint(0, 1_000, 1_100_000))

perfplot.show(
    setup=lambda n: s_num.iloc[:int(n)], 

    kernels=[
        lambda s: s.nunique() == 1,
        lambda s: is_unique(s)
    ],

    labels=['nunique', 'first_vs_rest'],
    n_range=[2**k for k in range(0, 20)],
    xlabel='N'
)
```

[image]

---

And below are the timings for a **`pd.DataFrame`**. Let's compare too with a `numba` approach, which is especially useful here since we can take advantage of short-cutting as soon as we see a repeated value in a given column (*note: the numba approach will only work with numerical data*):

```
from numba import njit

@njit
def unique_cols_nb(a):
    n_cols = a.shape[1]
    out = np.zeros(n_cols, dtype=np.int32)
    for i in range(n_cols):
        init = a[0, i]
        for j in a[1:, i]:
            if j != init:
                break
        else:
            out[i] = 1
    return out
```

If we compare the three methods:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.concatenate([np.random.randint(0, 1_000, (500_000, 200)), 
                                  np.zeros((500_000, 10))], axis=1))

perfplot.show(
    setup=lambda n: df.iloc[:int(n),:], 

    kernels=[
        lambda df: (df.nunique(0) == 1).values,
        lambda df: unique_cols_nb(df.values).astype(bool),
        lambda df: unique_cols(df) 
    ],

    labels=['nunique', 'unique_cols_nb', 'unique_cols'],
    n_range=[2**k for k in range(0, 20)],
    xlabel='N'
)
```

[image]

Comment: We can check if no. of unique values in the column is 1.

Comment: Finding the unique values has a needlessly high complexity to check this. It is included in the performance plots to make it clear @AnupamKumar

Comment: You are right, I totally forgot about performance.

Answer (score 19):

Update using `np.unique`

```
len(np.unique(df.counts))==1
False
```

Or

```
len(set(df.counts.tolist()))==1
```

Or

```
df.counts.eq(df.counts.iloc[0]).all()
False
```

Or

```
df.counts.std()==0
False
```

Comment: This: df.counts.is_unique -  didnt work for me, but df.counts.nunique() == 1 works. I am running python 2.7 on windows.

Comment: @MEdwin I mean your pandas version .

Comment: My pandas version is : 0.23.4

Comment: @MEdwin check the link https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.is_unique.html, if still return error , please file a bug in github

Comment: Bad answer: `is_unique` checks that values in a column are unique, i.e. there are no duplicates. What was asked is checking that all values in a column are the same, which is quite different.

Answer (score 6):

I prefer:

```
df['counts'].eq(df['counts'].iloc[0]).all()
```

I find it the easiest to read and it works across all value types. I have also find it fast enough in my experience.

Comment: It would be great to explain why this method would be preferable than another.

Comment: Added the explanation.

Comment: Warning: This will return False if df['counts'] is all None.

Answer (score 1):

I think `nunique` does much more work than necessary.  Iteration can stop at the first difference.  This simple and generic solution uses `itertools`:

```
import itertools

def all_equal(iterable):
    "Returns True if all elements are equal"
    g = itertools.groupby(iterable)
    next(g, None)
    try:
        return not next(g, False)
    except TypeError:  # pd.NA next to a different value?
        return False

all_equal(df.counts)
```

The try-except is needed because `itertools.groupby` [is incompatible](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75233893/357313) with `pd.NA`.

One can use this even to find *all* columns with constant contents in one go:

```
constant_columns = df.columns[df.apply(all_equal)]
```

---

A slightly more readable but less performant alternative:

```
df.counts.min() == df.counts.max()
```

Add `skipna=False` here if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

One simple and efficient way is to check that each row has a unique value. This is accomplished by measuring the length of the unique output of each row.
Assuming a `df` is pd.DataFrame, this can be done like this:

```
unique = df.apply(lambda row: len(row.unique()) == 1, axis=1)
```

Comment: unique = df.apply(lambda row: len(row.unique()) == 1, axis=1)[0] looks better

Comment: unique = df.apply(lambda row: len(row.unique()) == 1, axis=1)[0]

Answer (score 1):

```
##++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
## Function to check all elements in a df column is same
##+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
def check_all_are_equal_in_a_column_df(data_frame, column_name):
    data_list = data_frame[column_name].unique()
    data_set = set(data_list)
    if((len(data_set)) == 1):
        return_data = 1
    else:
        return_data = 0
    return return_data
```

Comment: Hello, please don't post code only and add an explantation as to why you think that this is the optimal solution. People are supposed to learn from your answer, which might not occur if they just copy paste code without knowing why it should be used.

Answer (score 0):

The default method by scipy.stats.linregress is:

```
same_val = np.amax(x) == np.amin(x) and len(x) > 1
```