# Check if all list values in dataframe column are the same

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with one of the column as a list:

```
df =
                        list_column
             0         [a b c d ...]
             1         [a b c d ...]
             2         [b a c d ...]
             ...        ...
```

How to check if list in all the rows for `list_column` are identical? In the above example, expected output is `False` because row 2 has a different list. Lists should be identical in the order in which the elements are present and not just merely the elements themselves.

I tried the solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54405704/check-if-all-values-in-dataframe-column-are-the-same): It gives me an error:

```
AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'all'
```

Comment: `len(df['list_column'].unique())==1` ?

Comment: `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`

Comment: same error. `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`, with paranthesis update.

Comment: ahh okay , the column is of lists my bad , try `df['list_column'].map(tuple).nunique()==1` ?