# Can itertools.groupby use pd.NA?

Tags: python, pandas, itertools-groupby

I [tried using](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59543818/357313) `itertools.groupby` with a pandas Series. But I got:

> TypeError: boolean value of NA is ambiguous

Indeed some of my values are `NA`.

This is a minimal reproducible example:

```
import pandas as pd
import itertools

g = itertools.groupby([pd.NA,0])
next(g)
next(g)
```

Comparing a `NA` always [results in](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.0.0/user_guide/missing_data.html#propagation-in-arithmetic-and-comparison-operations) `NA`, so `g.__next__` does `while NA` and [fails](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.0.0/user_guide/missing_data.html#na-in-a-boolean-context).

Is there a way to solve this, so `itertools.groupby` works with `NA` values? Or should I just accept it and use a different route to my (whatever) goal?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Can you give some context?

Comment: You can do it with `np.nan` if its an option.

Comment: Sure I can find other ways. I just want to make sure `itertools.groupby` and `pd.NA` are incompatible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using a key function in `itertools.groupby` to convert `pd.NA` to `None`? Since `==` doesn't produce the desired output with `pd.NA`, we can use the `is` operator to perform identity comparison instead.

```py
import pandas as pd
import itertools

arr = [pd.NA, pd.NA, 0, 1, 1]
keyfunc = lambda x: None if (x is pd.NA) else x
for key, group in itertools.groupby(arr, key=keyfunc):
    print(key, list(group))
```

Output:

```
None [<NA>, <NA>]
0 [0]
1 [1, 1]
```