# check columns in DataFrame for constant values explanation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to check a  big DataFrame for constant columns and make a 2 list. The first for the columnnames with only zeros the second with the columnnames of constant values (excluding 0)

I found a solution (A in code) at [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20209600/pandas-dataframe-remove-constant-column) but I dont understand it. A is making what i want but i dont know how and how i can get the list.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = [[0,1,1],[0,1,2],[0,1,3]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])

A  =df.loc[:, (df != df.iloc[0]).any()]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
m1 = (df == 0).all()
m2 = (df == df.iloc[0]).all()
a  = df.columns[m1].tolist()
b  = df.columns[~m1 & m2].tolist()
print (a)
['A']
print (b)
['B']
```

**Explanation**:

First compare all values by `0`:

```
print (df == 0)
      A      B      C
0  True  False  False
1  True  False  False
2  True  False  False
```

Then test if all values are Trues by [`DataFrame.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html):

```
print ((df == 0).all())
A     True
B    False
C    False
dtype: bool
```

Then compare first values of row by [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
print (df == df.iloc[0])
      A     B      C
0  True  True   True
1  True  True  False
2  True  True  False
```

And test again by `all`:

```
print ((df == df.iloc[0]).all())
A     True
B     True
C    False
dtype: bool
```

because exclude `0` chain inverted first mask by `~` with `&` for `bitwise AND`:

```
print (~m1 & m2)
A    False
B     True
C    False
dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 2):

This seems like a clean way to do what you want:

```
m1 = df.eq(0).all()
m2 = df.nunique().eq(1) & ~m1

m1[m1].index, m2[m2].index
# (Index(['A'], dtype='object'), Index(['B'], dtype='object'))
```

---

m1 gives you a boolean of columns that all have zeros:

```
m1
A     True
B    False
C    False
dtype: bool
```

m2 gives you all columns with unique values, but not zeros (second condition re-uses the first)

```
m2
A    False
B     True
C    False
dtype: bool
```

Deriving your lists is trivial from these masks.

Comment: Thanks, i already tried it with `nunique()`but i got some problems with my dataframe `ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().` In this lil example it worked fine but in my case i was not able to finde the problem

Comment: @credenco Start by doing `df = df.select_dtypes('int')` and try it again.